# Filter based on a values in all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get records within the date range. he query should filter only, where the value in colA  or ColB or ColC is greater then 0 and not equal to null. Right now, if I try this query, I get range range of 2012, 2011 and 0 values in all columns. Any help is appreciated. Thank you. I am using sql 2008
Query:

```
select  ColA, ColC, ColB 
from tableA join 
     tableB on tableA.id = TableB.id
where ColA > 0 
   or ColB > 0 
   or ColC > 0 
  and tableB .Collection Date between 01-01-2013 and 12-31-2013
```

Data:

```
date range colA  colB   ColB
2/4/2013   402   88     null
5/4/2012   null  501    522
12/6/2013  110   550    null
12/20/2013 85    null   101
12/8/2013  null  null   null
6/17/2012  852   225    null
3/22/2013  null  null   null
3/2/2013   null  null   null
```

The output should be-

```
date range  colA    colB    ColB
2/4/2013    402     88      null
12/6/2013   110     550     null
12/20/2013  85      null    101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using brackets:

```
select  ColA, ColC, ColB 
from tableA join 
     tableB on tableA.id = TableB.id
where (ColA > 0 or ColB > 0 or ColC > 0 )
   and tableB.[Collection Date] between 01-01-2013 and 12-31-2013
```

**OR** using `COALESCE`:

```
select  ColA, ColC, ColB 
from tableA join 
     tableB on tableA.id = TableB.id
where COALESCE(ColA,ColB,ColC) IS NOT NULL
   and tableB.[Collection Date] between 01-01-2013 and 12-31-2013
```

Comment: Aahh... I missed the brackets. Thank you @Raging Bull